# Can a scholar repeat healing hands every 10 minutes?

Tags: class-feature, healing, adventures-in-middle-earth

In *Adventures in Middle-Earth*, the scholar class has the "Hands of a Healer" ability:

> If you can touch a creature, you may expend one Healing Die per action, instantly granting them hit points equal to 1d8 plus your wisdom modifier...If instead you tend the creature for at least 10 minutes..., then you may multiply the 1d8 by your proficiency modifier...

Can a scholar repeat healing hands every 10 minutes, spending more healing dice?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, these are two different abilities, so it's a bit confusing that the descriptions overlap.  I would allow players to spend one healing die for every ten minutes spent healing.

1. For the first option, the cost is one healing die and one action and
   the benefit is 1d8 + WIS hp.
2. For the second option, the cost is one healing die and ten minutes
   (about 100 actions) and the benefit is (1d8 * prof) + WIS hp.

There is no "once per day" or "once per short rest" for either rule. The number of times it can be used is limited only by (a) the amount of time it takes and (b) the number of healing dice available to use.

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE. The [tour], [help], [ask], and [answer] provide guidance on how to best use the SE format.  The edit I did was for format and what I thought was better "flow" of your points. Feel free to revert to your original if you don't like how that edit looks.